# Styled Components generated class names are messing my layout with React-Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, styled-components

I'm using react-bootstrap along with styled components. So far everything was perfect but now there is a `div` with a `className` that keeps changing every now and then. This `div` has a height of `450px` and it's on top of my Main Layout, limiting the height of everything else.

The syntax i'm using on my components is something like:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Styles = styled.div`
  .input-group-prepend {
    padding-top:11px;
    padding-right:10px;
  }

  .login-input {
    background-color: #6C63FF;
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 240px;
    color:white;
    font-size:0.80rem;
  }

export const Input = (props) => {
  const { type, placeholder, } = props
  return (
    <Styles>
      <InputGroup className="my-4">
        <InputGroup.Prepend>
            {props.children}
        </InputGroup.Prepend>
        <FormControl
          className='login-input'
          placeholder={placeholder}
          aria-label={placeholder}
        />
      </InputGroup>
    </Styles>
  )
}
```

**My App Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Routes from './Routes'

import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'
import { theme } from './theme'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Routes />
            </ThemeProvider>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

[image: ChromeTools]

**What i've tried so far:**

- Removed the ThemeProvider
- Put the routes straight into index.js (Can i do this or is a bad practice?)
- Reinstalled the packages via NPM
- Refactoring on components as well

Is there something I'm missing and if that is the case, what is it?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you further specify what your expected result is and what exactly is not working as planned? Is it a problem that the class names are generated randomly? And to answer your other question: I would suggest using a Routes.jsx file and putting everything there but that's just to keep things separated from each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading this answer: [Random classes getting displayed when we use styled components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59961697/random-classes-getting-displayed-when-we-use-styled-components)

It looks like your `<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>` is not actually receiving a correct 'Theme'.

What it looks like is that you are receiving your Hash onto the element as explained in the above Stack answer, but you are not actually receiving your styles from the Theme.

So I assume that's where you are going wrong. Check your Theme component.

Comment: I had to come up with a workaround for this by creating a new component with styled components called Layout and setting the WIDTH and HEIGHT to 100vh to kinda 'fix it'. But then i saw that the problem was in my global.css file. I did the usual body,html,#root{weight:100%} and magically i didn't need the component anymore. Thanks for yout help!

Comment: Happy to help :)